# custom post template ignored after altering permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I've built a site with a custom post type called Testimonials and am using a custom template to display the posts *edit: template name is page-testimonials.php*. 
All is working as expected with the default permalink structure, however when I set the permalinks to /%postname%/ the custom template is ignored and the posts are showed on a blog archive....

Here's the code I've used to register the post type. Have I missed something required to make it use the proper template with custom permalinks?

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'testimonial',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Testimonials' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Testimonial' ),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
                'new_item' => __('New Item'),
                'view_item' => __('View Item'),    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
                'new_item' => __('New Item'),
                'view_item' => __('View Item')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'testimonials',
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'page',
            'hierarchical' => true,
           'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
           'query_var' => true)
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: What is the name of your template?

Comment: the template is page-testimonials.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom post types have a different hierarchy than pages or posts.

They'll use `single-{{post_type}}.php` and fall back to `single.php`. Post type archives will use `archive-{{post_type}}.php` and fall back to `archive.php`.

Your question isn't super clear, but if you want your custom post type's singular page to use the `page-testimonials.php` template, rename it to `single-testimonials.php`.

I suspect, however, that you meant that `page-testimonials.php` was display a list of the testimonials.  In which case, rename it to `archive-testomonials.php` and it should work fine.  What happened before is you saw the permalink `yoursite.com/?page_id={{some_number}}`.  Which works -- that's always going to be a page, but with the post type as you registered it (with `'has_archive' => true`) `yoursite.com/testimonials` attempts to display the custom post type archive.

A final note: if you did any query modifications or secondary queries to get the `testimonials` post type in your `page-testimonials.php` template, you can remove those. WordPress will take care of making sure the correct items are available in the `archive-{{post_type}}.php` template.

You should also have a look at the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Comment: Awesome, well written and concise answer. You sir are a legend. To state the obvious that solved my question and gave me some great further insight into how wordpress operates.

Answer (score 0):

i see an error:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'testimonial',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Testimonials' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Testimonial' ),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
            'new_item' => __('New Item'),
            'view_item' => __('View Item'),    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
            'new_item' => __('New Item'),
            'view_item' => __('View Item')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'testimonials'),  **<---- miss )**
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => true,
       'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
       'query_var' => true)
    )
);
```

}

Comment: Please explain where

Comment: before:
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'testimonials',

after:
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'testimonials'),

Comment: You should edit your answer and add your comments to that. Always when you answer, give a short explanation to any code that you add. Code alone is meaningless, so are links